Sampled exponential with zero order hold spectrum
I want to compare the analytical expression of sampling a complex exponential and then passing through zero order hold (zoh) system by the spectrum obtained from FFT, the magnitude matches but the phase response does not. I hope someone helps me figure out why.
We begin by sampling $e^{-j\omega_{0} t}$ by $f_{s}$ sampling frequency, resulting in a spectrum of $X(f)= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\delta(f-kf_s-f_o)$, the zoh frequency response is given by $e^{-j\pi\frac{f}{f_s}} sinc(\frac{f}{fs})$ where sinc function is defined as $sinc(x)=\frac{sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$, so the resulting spectrum after the zoh will be $X(f)= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\delta(f-kf_s-f_o) e^{-j \pi \frac{f}{f_s}}sinc(\frac{f}{f_s})$, using the sifting property of the impulse we can get $ Y(f)= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\delta(f-kf_s-f_o) e^{-j \pi (k +\frac{f_o}{f_s}})sinc(k+\frac{f_o}{f_s})$ = $ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\delta(f-kf_s-f_o) e^{-j \pi \frac{f_o}{f_s}} e^{-j \pi k} sinc(k+\frac{f_o}{f_s})$ = $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\delta(f-kf_s-f_o) e^{-j \pi \frac{f_o}{f_s}} e^{-j 2\pi k} |sinc(k+\frac{f_o}{f_s})|$ finally reaching $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\delta(f-kf_s-f_o) e^{-j \pi \frac{f_o}{f_s}} |sinc(k+\frac{f_o}{f_s})| $
The following simple python code generates zero order hold complex exponential and performs an FFT operation and compare it with the expected spectrum.
"""
Zero order hold 
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# input parameters 
fs=2000  # simulation max. frequency
Ts=1/fs # simulation min. step. (simulation step duration)
fzoh=10    # Zero order hold (Zoh) sampling frequency
Tzoh=1/fzoh    # Zoh duration
fout=1  # output frequency
Tout=1/fout
fout_cycles=4 # number of fout complete cycles 

#signal generation
fout_zoh_samples=(fzoh/fout)*fout_cycles      # Required number of Zoh samples 
n_zoh=np.arange(0,fout_zoh_samples,1)   
sim_samples=fout_zoh_samples * (fs/fzoh)  # Required simulation steps = Required Zoh samples * (Ts samples per Tzoh)
n_sim=np.arange(0,sim_samples,1)            # simulation step index
Sampled_exp=np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*fout*n_zoh*Tzoh)
Sampled_exp_zoh=np.repeat(Sampled_exp,Tzoh/Ts)      # repeat the sampled signal to represent Zoh signal
# ideal exponent
t=n_sim*Ts
ideal_exp=np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*fout*t)     # continous exponential

#signals plot
# real(exp)  
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,np.real(ideal_exp),label='Ideal cos')
plt.plot(t,np.real(Sampled_exp_zoh),label='Zoh cos')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Real exp')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Real exp.')
# imag(exp)  
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,np.imag(ideal_exp),label='Ideal sin')
plt.plot(t,np.imag(Sampled_exp_zoh),label='Zoh sin')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Imag exp')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Imag exp.')

# FFT 
fft_samples=len(n_sim)
zoh_fft = np.fft.fft(((Sampled_exp_zoh)))
zoh_fft = zoh_fft / (fft_samples)  # Normalize
freq_zoh_fft = np.fft.fftfreq(fft_samples, 1/(fs))
zoh_fft_abs = np.abs(zoh_fft)
zoh_fft_angle = np.angle(zoh_fft)

zoh_fft_dB=20*np.log10(zoh_fft_abs+1e-80)

# expected FFT spectrum
harmonic_index=np.arange(-100 ,100)           # calculate exptected FFT spectrum for those #harmoics
harmonic_freq=harmonic_index*fzoh+fout      # expected Zoh FFT images' frequencies
expected_fft=np.abs(np.sinc(harmonic_freq/fzoh)) * np.exp(-1j*np.pi*(fout/fzoh))
expected_fft_dB=20*np.log10(np.abs(expected_fft))
expected_fft_angle=np.angle(expected_fft)

#compare FFT mag. response
plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq_zoh_fft,zoh_fft_dB,label='Zoh FFT')
plt.plot(harmonic_freq,expected_fft_dB,label='Expected FFT')
plt.legend()
plt.title('FFT mag.')
plt.xlabel('freq')
plt.ylabel('FFT mag (dB)')

#compare FFT phase. response

#to avoid making the plot messy, avoid plotting the phase for frequencies with
# zero magnitude, and plot only the phase for harmonic frequencies

#find indices for required frequencies only
freq_indices = [np.argmin(np.abs(freq_zoh_fft - f)) for f in harmonic_freq]

plt.figure()
plt.stem(freq_zoh_fft[freq_indices],zoh_fft_angle[freq_indices],'r',label='Zoh FFT')
plt.stem(harmonic_freq,expected_fft_angle,label='Expected FFT')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('freq')
plt.title('FFTspectrum angle')
plt.ylabel('FFT spectrum phase (angle)')
plt.show(block=False)

## Calc. slope of the phase to get this unkown delay 
freq_index1=5
freq_index2=7

Delay=(zoh_fft_angle[freq_indices[freq_index2]]-zoh_fft_angle[freq_indices][freq_index1]) / ( 2*np.pi * (freq_zoh_fft[freq_indices][freq_index2]-freq_zoh_fft[freq_indices][freq_index1]))
print("Delay: " + str(Delay))
print("Delay/Ts: " + str(Delay/Ts))

Some notes regarding the given code:

It up-sample the sequence using fs frequency to represent the zoh signal as (Tzoh/Ts) samples
For the FFT phase response, I have plotted only the images to avoid very messy plot as most bins are zero
The magnitude response somehow has a good match as shown (except at high frequencies which I guess is due to aliasing, as the zoh signal is not bandlimited)
The FFT phase response has a weird linear phase though I expected a constant one (based on the aforementioned analytical expression), when I calculated the slope and hence the delay associated with that spectrum I found it to be $-0.5 T_{s}$, so there is a response of $e^{ 0.5j\omega T_{s} }$ somewhere and an additional pi phase shift for the negative frequencies, I could not figure it from where it came, if I removed that phase from the FFT manually, then the spectrum will match.
Update: the additional PI issue was due to a mistake in the analytical expression where I replaced the sinc by its absolute value and (-1)^k which was valid only for positive frequencies, what remains now is the Ts/2 delay.






There's a theoretical answer to this.

what do you mean? where can I find that theoretical answer? thanks.

Well, everything is mathematically well-defined.  There is a well-defined spectrum for a decaying exponential pulse.  There is a well-defined spectrum for what happens when you apply sampling.  And there is a well-defined spectrum for the application of the zero-order hold.

I believe it just  means the signal should be considered over  $-2.0 \leq t \lt +2.0$ rather than over $0.0 \leq t \lt 4.0$.
That difference will add a delay  of 2.0 seconds to the response,  which will give a linear phase.

The effect you are implying is already included in the zero order hold transfer function by adding the delay within the transfer function, so it should be there already. Additionally, that delay is simulation step /2 , not the zero order hold duration.

@MohamedOsama In that case, the issue is an off-by-half-a-sample error.

Yes, but I don't know why
